# How do you quickly enable/disable a monitor?

Tags: windows-vista, multiple-monitors

Is there any alternative to UltraMon to be able to quickly turn a screen on and off.

I'm using multiple monitors and but have a piece of software with features that doesn't work when two monitors are enabled.

Windows Vista, nvidia, using the windows control panel currently.

Comment: Linux? Windows? Mac OSX? Don't just assume that we telepathically know what OS you use. I'm guessing it's Windows though, as Linux and Mac OSX users would typically point out what OS they use.

Comment: Well, he was talking about UltraMon, so chances are pretty high that he's referring to Windows.

Comment: I assume it's not a laptop with a switch-monitor-config key (Fn+F3, Fn+F4, or something like that)...

Comment: Use resswitch: http://www.naughter.com/qres.html
  Enable: `resswitch /device:\\.\DISPLAY2`
  Disable: `resswitch /device:\\.\DISPLAY2 /detach`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the easiest way to switch on/off the external monitor is to use Windows' own control panel. I have a workstation with two monitors, but one of them doubles as an external monitor for my laptop. When I need it for my laptop, I just flip it off using the control panel (right-click on the desktop and select "properties").

Comment: That is the slowest and most annoying solution, in my opinion.

Comment: Well, at least it works. Unless all the other solutions I've tried.

Answer (score 1):

You could use any automation software to manipulate the control panel. I like [AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/AutoIt/) myself

BTW. Is this really a programming question? If it is then I'd advice to fix the software rather than look for hacky workarounds. Multiple and/or large monitors are becoming quite popular these days.